# HTML won't render code block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax-highlighting, google-code-prettify

So I'm using Google code prettify with AnchorCMS. All other languages *but* HTML work. This is what I'm trying to use.

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-html">
<!DOCTYPE html>
</pre>
```

But I think that the editor is interpreting the HTML within the `<pre>` tags and that's why Its not working. [Here's](http://colourity.com/posts/html-doctype-declaration) what happens when I try to show the above code. And there's [this](http://colourity.com/posts/simple-alert-in-js) example that I used `<pre class="prettyprint lang-js">` on. I'm not really sure what to do now. Any ideas? Also sorry for the direct link to my website. I wouldn't of been able to show it on JSFiddle

Comment: you're lucky with js) try `for(i=0; i<10; i++);` code, it should be breaked too

Comment: I'm shocked that the title "HTML won't work" was actually accurate and didn't get closed by the stackoverflow moderators.

Comment: The title is accurate within a very limited context which the title doesn't introduce.  My immediate reaction was to down-vote it.  I'll hold off on that, but I encourage the OP to change the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zzzzBov is right, the browser requires the entities in your markup you want displayed to be encoded.

But according to Chromes source view, it seems your CMS might automatically unescape your markup again when it outputs it:

[image]

In [this bug report](https://github.com/anchorcms/anchor-cms/issues/306#issuecomment-17047967) from somebody having the same issue, the maintainer recommends a custom theme function to get around this problem:

> In version 0.9 and 1.0 the content of a post and pages are not changed
>   when saved to the database, so if you input html code like **text**
>   it will be rendered as html, if you want html encoded you will have to
>   input it encoded like <b>text</b>.
>
> To get around this you could use a custom function in the theme
>   functions.php file to handle the content exactly how you like.
>
> ```
> function mytheme_article_content() {
>     // if you just want the raw content you saved
>     return Registry::prop('article', 'html');
>
>     // if you want the content to be parsed with markdown
>     $md = new Markdown;
>     return $md->transform(Registry::prop('article', 'html'));
>
>     // if you want to encode any html in you posts
>     return htmlentities(Registry::prop('article', 'html'), ENT_NOQUOTES, Config::app('encoding'));
> }
> ```
>
> So you have a few options you can mix around with to get the output you want. And in your
>   template just replace article_html with mytheme_article_content.

I would wager that the last line (`return htmlentities`...) might be the version you are looking for, so try and delete the two lines above it starting with `return` and call `mytheme_article_content` in your template file as the maintainer suggested.

Answer (score 12):

The contents of the `<pre>` tag need to be HTML encoded.

Instead of using `<`, `>`, `"`, and `&` characters, you'll need to use their encoded counterparts:

- `<` becomes `&lt;`
- `>` becomes `&gt;`
- `"` becomes `&quot;`
- `&` becomes `&amp;`

Comment: So it would look like this? `&lt;pre class="prettyprint lang-html"&gt;`

Comment: @user3444414, no, you want the **contents** of the `<pre>` tag to use the entities, the `<pre>` tag itself needs to still be raw HTML.

Comment: This is what I currently have `<pre class="prettyprint lang-html">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
</pre>` But all I get is a blank code box. As seen here http://colourity.com/posts/html-doctype-declaration

Comment: I just tried doing this on the developer tools since it won't work on the editor. And it still wont work.....

Comment: is this also true for <code> </code> ? I am seeing same behaviour, but cant encode it in this case

Answer (score 0):

try to

```
$('.prettyprint').text('<!DOCTYPE html>');
```

or

```
document.querySelector('.prettyprint').innerText('<!DOCTYPE html>');
```

This automatically encode html entities for a browser

If you are use serverside script language like PHP better to encode it on the server:

**PHP:**

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-html">
   <?=htmlspecialchars('<!DOCTYPE html>');?>
</pre>
```

Comment: yes, also wrap it in `window.onload=function(){ ... }` or `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`

Comment: use you PHP on the server?

Comment: Yes I use PHP on the server

Comment: use [htmlspecialchars](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for this on the serverside

Comment: Take a look at what I get now. http://colourity.com/posts/html-doctype-declaration

Comment: And `$('.prettyprint').text('<!DOCTYPE html>');` is only the `!DOCTYPE html`. I'm going to be typing tons of lines of code on the posts and don't really want to do that every time I post

Comment: I'm using a CMS. So Its dynamic content. Not a static PHP file

Comment: `document.querySelector('pre').innerText = ('<!DOCTYPE html>');` worked

Comment: are you really wrote `<?php=` ?

Comment: But will I have to change `document.querySelector('pre').innerText = ('<!DOCTYPE html>');` the `<!DOCTYPE html>` part every time I post HTML? I just want to use HTML like any other language

Comment: need `<?php echo ` or `<?=` here

Comment: That's what I did. And I got the same issue. So I tried changing it to `<?php`

Comment: Check the source. That's what I did.

Comment: `<? =htmlspecialchars('<!DOCTYPE html>');?>` in your code... extra space, but php short tags not worked, try `<?php echo htmlspecialchars('<!DOCTYPE html>');?>` also

Comment: I got rid of the space and its still the same. And `<?php echo htmlspecialchars('<!DOCTYPE html>');?>` didn't work either.

Comment: I see... php doesn't work here... I think you are edit a template... You should find where in php code you fill this template with code example

Comment: and wrap this variable to htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 0):

This must be handled on the server. I guess you have a CMS system with plugins. (Looks like you could be using WP.)

Then try a plugin for code prettyfying. Such a plugin can handle this for you.

If it does not work, then ask the plugin author if s/he wants to fix it.

Comment: I'm using AnchorCMS as stated in my question. Which doesn't support plugins just yet.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not notice. ;-) -- Then follow the advices of zzzzBov and vp_arth (the PHP part). Unfortunately it does not get easier than that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather use following HTML tag to do so:

```
<xmp >
    <!doctype html>
</xmp>
```

For sure it will work.

Comment: Will you please elaborate.

Comment: It doesn't display <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 0):

This `<pre class="prettyprint lang-html">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</pre>` displays `<!DOCTYPE html>` ìn my browser (chrome). This is what your page source code is atm

```
<pre class="lang-html">
     <!DOCTYPE html>
</pre>
```

Page might not be updated ?

Comment: Just updated it to your code, but here's whats happening. Once I save the post it turns into `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: No. The editor gets rid of the `&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;`, so it won't work.

Comment: As posted in the bounty description and various other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have some malformed HTML which could cause some elements to not render as requested.

[image]

Also, where is the source coming from -- a database ?, could you paste exactly what it looks like if you took the data raw from the database (using Navicat or another non-web based tool), and pasted it into Windows Notepad (exactly what is stored .. may have to run it through an online encoder to see)

Comment: Its coming from a database. This is what I get `<pre class="prettyprint lang-html">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</pre>`